# an unwanted twist

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves

I have a twist when I move my mesh I tried the tilt and clear tilt option also by setting the mean tilt to 180° or by manually moving the vertices but nothing works.

The twist problem below.[image]

Comment: I think this is a problem where file linking would help. You got some sort of armature curve link set up here, which could make it tricky to describe exactly what you did, and what the settings are for everything, https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Twisted seems to be the bone not the curve ... Try to change curve shape if make it any difference ... +1 TheLabCat